# Titanium : Restrict recording video size to 15MB

Tags: android, video, titanium

In my Titanium application I want to restrict video size to `15MB`. I have added line below to my code.

> intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.sizeLimit",15728640)

But it is not working. 
Please help me.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context?

Comment: I need to stop video recording when video size reaches 15MB. It is working fine in Native but not in Titanium

Comment: Could you provide a more complete code sample to show how you at opening the camera to record and then receive the video?